# Count mismatches in list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have two lists arr_list1 and arr_list2 which are both lists of lists. they are both exactly the same size. I need to count how many elements differ between the two, per list. for example,

```
arr_list1 = [[0,1,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]
arr_list2 = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,0,1]]
```

I would like to get result = (1,2,0)

Is there a 'simple' way of doing this that doesnt require loops?

Comment: both lists have the same name

Comment: Unless you're willing to use a DataFrame, then iterating over the lists would be the best option. As you're comparing them side by side `zip` would be your friend on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
arr_list1 = [[0,1,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]
arr_list2 = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,0,1]]
print np.sum(np.asarray(arr_list1) != np.asarray(arr_list2),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip to compare the differences:

```
arr_list1 = [[0,1,-1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]
arr_list2 = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,0,1]]

def get_differences(arr_list1, arr_list2):
    all_differences = []
    for a, b in zip(arr_list1, arr_list2):
        sum_differences = 0
        for a_item, b_item in zip(a, b):
            if a_item != b_item:
                sum_differences += 1
        all_differences.append(sum_differences)
    return all_differences

print get_differences(arr_list1, arr_list2)
```

Comment: Yea you approach makes perfect sense, but the list actually contains -1 and 1, not 0 and 1! i just used that for clarity in the question. Is there a way to modify this so that it works based on mismatch between values instead of taking the subtraction of the two?

Comment: I've edited my answer to do a standard comparison. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate two lists and use `sum()` method to count the mismatches

```
a1 = [[0,1,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]
a2 = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[1,0,1]]


print [sum([a1[i][j]!=a2[i][j] for j in range(len(a1[i]))]) for i in range(len(a1))]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 0]
```